# открытие окошка редактирования для календаря

Tags: javascript

как сделать так что б при клике на ячейку таблицы, открывалось окно в которое бы вписывались данные события и оно сохранялось в `localstorage`
как на картинке, как записать в `localstorage` я понимаю, а как сделать так что б при клике на другое окошко, это пропадало и как правильно добавлять к ячейке это окошко.
главное условие нельзя использовать jquery
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

https://jsfiddle.net/ovutdzef/1/

Comment: я не ищу готовой работы, просто дайте совет как бы вы поступили в решении данной задачи

Comment: я бы написал функцию закрытия окна, и использовал бы её на текущее окно при клике на другую ячейку

Comment: Используйте jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Достаточно окну добавить id, и в событие "onclick" добавить удаление этого окна если, оно есть на странице.

```
var emptyCreateEventWindow = '<div class="create_event" id="openWindow"><div class="event_input_container"><input type="text" placeholder="Событие"><input type="text" placeholder="День, месяц, год"><input type="text" placeholder="Имена уччастников"></div><textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="8" placeholder="Описание"></textarea><input type="submit" value="Готово" class="create_event_button "><input type="submit" value="Удалить" class="create_event_button edit-cancel"><div class="close_event">+</div></div>';
function addHandlers(table) {
  var tds = table.querySelectorAll("td");
  for (var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {

    tds[i].onclick = function() {
        if(document.getElementById('openWindow'))
        document.getElementById('openWindow').remove();
      this.innerHTML = emptyCreateEventWindow;
    };
  }
}
```